# How do i append custom parameters on my page when i hit back from facebook wall?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-sharer

My requirement is very simple

1. From my website, I will share an article/page on facebook.
2. My article will appear on facebook wall.
3. On clicking my facebook article, my website opens in a new tab. Here
   I am expecting to append some **custom params** like shown below.

**Expected Result**:

> https://mywebsite.com/productdetail/id?utm_campaign=share&utm_medium=social&utm_source=Facebook

For this, I tried to append my fb sharing widget with params on clicking facebook share icon.This failed to append params and being **trimmed** on facebook wall. Please find the below-sharing widget url. Refer 1.png

Our code will produce sharing widget URL as:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?app_id=123123123123123&scrape=true&u=www.xyz.com%2Fstore%2Fmywebsite%2FProductDetail%2FPartyAllNightEyeOpeningNoSmudgeMascara%2F_%2FAskusku920140.prod1000045.en__US.HXLT%3Fpdp%3Dtrue&utm_campaign=share&utm_medium=social&utm_source=Facebook
```

Also, I tried with og:url which was not working as expected and page loads normally(being referred from input URL i.e., article page) when I click from facebook wall. Refer 2.png

After sharing it on facebook wall, on hover of article on my wall.. URL is not appending my custom params.

None of the solutions helped us to achieve adding our custom params on facebook wall(article details).

On facebook wall, my utm params i.e., `utm_campaign=share&utm_medium=social&utm_source=Facebook` being trimmed by facebook. I need this to be as it is and when user clicks on facebook wall should open URL in a new tab with my **utm params** as well.

Can anyone help us achieving this functionality??

Also, when I tried changing my article landing page URL where facebook share icon being clicked, then few of my custom params being posted on facebook wall properly and appearing same when I come back from facebook wall. So, assuming facebook is retrieving/referring input URL instead of og:url or sharing widget URL.

Looking for a better solution without changing my landing page URL and to achieve custom params appending when we hit back from facebook wall using og:url or widget URL.

Thanks in advance.

Please refer below screenshots.

[image: fb sharing widget with custom params]
[image: og:url]

Comment: That is not possible. Facebook takes the og:url to be the “real” URL for this piece of content, and if you append additional GET parameters, they will be removed. And you don’t want to include them in the og:url either - because that makes it a _different_ URL than the original one, so likes/comments/shares would be split.

Comment: @CBroe - I understood this CBroe, but client is not agreeing with me and expecting to append those params at any cost. Is there any documentation which explains this trimming behaviour??